# how to catch boost message_queue returns false

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost::interprocess::message_queue and as per the definition given on 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html

```
message_queue(open_only_t open_only, const char * name);
```

- Opens a previously created process shared message queue with name "name". If the was not previously created or there are no free resources, the function returns false.

now what i can't understand is that how a constructor is returning a value? though it states " the **function** returns false" but afaik message_queue is supposed to be a constructor.

and also if it do return false can i catch that in a Boolean variable?

Comment: That's an error in the documentation, a constructor can't return anything.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html#idp49988992-bb <- current version of the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception` will be thrown instead, as the current documentation suggests.

So,

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
try {
    //Create a message_queue. If the queue
    //exists throws an exception
    message_queue mq
        (create_only         //only create
         ,"message_queue"     //name
         ,100                 //max message number
         ,100                 //max message size
        );
} catch (interprocess_exception const& ipe)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: #" << ipe.get_error_code() << ", " << ipe.what() << "\n";
}
```

When run twice, will print

```
Error: #9, File exists
```

Comment: yeah.. i am doing the same now, but unfortunately i was referencing to old documentation which seems to say that constructor "returned false", that's what was troubling me. Thanks for the answer anyway.